# Does $\exists e \in G \forall g \in G: e \circ g = g \circ e = g$ properly define the neutral element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'd like to know if this
$$\exists e \in G \forall g \in G: e \circ g = g \circ e = g$$
is a real and accepted definition of a neutral element that is right and left identity.

My textbook shows the following in the definition of a group:
$$\exists e \in G \forall g \in G: e \circ g = g$$ But later on there is the remark that the neutral element is "unique" and showing this: $$\forall g \in G: g \circ e = g$$

I'm still wrapping my head around mathematical notations so I hope this doesn't seem too trivial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. In the first definition, you require $e$ to be left- and right-neutral, whereas in the second one you only require $e$ to be left-neutral. But then you actually have to *prove* that it's also right-neutral.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not the definition of a neutral element but a statement that a neutral element exists.

Comment: The *definition* of a group says that at least one such element exist.  And then later a proposition *proves* that *only* one such unique element exists.  It's a *definition* that in a group an identity element exists.  It's a *provable proposition* that *only* one exists.

Comment: This is related to one of my pet grouses in books that claim to be doing formal mathematics (but it doesn't seem to bother most people). Almost all textbooks define a group with two separate axioms, one stating the existence of the neutral element $e$, and the next one asserting the existence of inverses. But the inverses axiom refers to $e$, which is not defined at that point, because we are now outside the scope of the "there exists" phrase. It is also genuinely ambiguous in the definition, because we do not know yet that the identity element is unique.

Comment: @Marktmeister thanks!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, aren't mathematical definitions written this way with quantifiers, or am I wrong to assume that that's a definition? Thanks by the way.

Comment: @fleablood, are you referring to the second statement as the proposition? I'm not really sure what you meant.

Comment: @DerekHolt, would this be sufficient to show the uniqueness of the neutral element?

$$\exists !e \in G \forall g \in G: g \circ e = e \circ g = g$$

Comment: @Jobran That statement asserts the uniqueness of the neutral element, so yes. But the point is that you can prove its uniqueness from the group axioms (or even from monoid axioms); you do not need to assume it.

Comment: @Jobran $\exists e \in G \forall g \in G: e \circ g = g \circ e = g$ says that there exists an element that is a left and right identity, gives it the name $e$, but doesn't claim that it is unique. $\exists e \in G \forall g \in G: e \circ g = g$ says that there is a left identity and gives it a name, but not that it is a right identity or that it is unique. And statement  $\forall g \in G: g \circ e = g$ is saying that the elements we called $e$ is a right identity..... tbc .....

Comment: continued.... it sounded like you were confused about whether being unique was part of the *axiomatic definition* of the identity element, or whether being unique was a *provable proposition* of the identity element.  My answer:  That an identity element is exists is a definition/axiom.  That it is unique, however, must be proven.  (BTW.... I'm not sure how you book could prove that a left identity must be a right identity unless you book states that every element has an element that is both a left and right inverse....)

Comment: @DerekHolt That doesn't bother me at all beause the axiom says there is at least one identity element and specifically names and identifies *one* of them (while implying there could, hypothetically, be others).  *THEN* (afterwards) it says every element has an inverse that pertains specifically to the *specifically* identified identity element (whille implying if there are other identity elements, which elements need not have inverses pertaining to). This is fine because this statement is an *axiom*. Final it proves there are no other identity elements. Nothing wrong with any of this.

Comment: @DerekHolt tl;dy " But the inverses axiom refers to e, which is not defined at that point"  Yes, it is defined!  The axiom stating an identity element, also defines $e$ as that element.  If there are multiple such identity elements, one specific one of them has been pointed out to be referred to as "$e$".  Then the axiom declaring inverses *axiomatically* pertains to *that one* and none of the hypothetical others.

Comment: @fleablood The reason $e$ is not defined at that point is because the scope of the "there exists" quantifier ends at the end of the statement of that axiom. It just needs a little rewording: Axiom: there exists $e\in G$ such that for all $g \in G$ we have (i) $eg=ge=g$ and (ii) there exists $g^{-1} \in G$ with $gg^{-1}=g^{-1}g=e$. But doing it that way ruins the traditional layout of the four axioms of a group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Or it could be i) there exists and $e\in G$ so that $eg=ge=g$ for all $g\in G$.  and ii) For every $g\in G$ there exists a $g^{-1}\in G$ so that $gg^{-1}=g^{-1}g=e$ *where $e$ is the element described in i)*.  I think that is clearly the implication and that should be fine.  It seems to me every case of seen no matter what the context claim:  "There exist a $w$ so that ..." has in so stating both claimed an object exist *and* simultaneously labelled the object as $w$ so any reference later to $w$ is understood to be the object described. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @mrtaurho I have yet to read and work through all the answers provided, but will sure do so once I'm through. Thanks for your answer, by the way!

Comment: @fleablood thanks, I think I understand now why the remark about the uniqueness of $e$ was made later on. I thought it could have simply been included in the second axiom.

Comment: @DerekHolt I would have to use the following axiom to derive a proof, or simply the 3rd axiom of groups? 
$$\forall g \in G \exists !g^{-1} \in G: g^{-1} \circ g = g \circ g^{-1} = e$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a left identity, i.e. an element $e\in G$ such that $e\circ g=g$ for all $g\in G$, this one already is a right identity aswell. To see this, go for a contradiction. Suppose $g\circ e\ne g$, then
\begin{align*}
g\circ e&\ne g\\
(g\circ e)\circ g&\ne g\circ g\\
g\circ (e\circ g)&\ne g\circ g\\
g\circ g&\ne g\circ g\\
g&\ne g
\end{align*}
The last step follows from multplying with the (left) inverse $g^{-1}$. The contradiction implies that $g\circ e=g$ for every left identity $e$ (see [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Left_and_Right_Identity_are_the_Same) for a simpler proof). Given a *left* identity is also a *right* identity, consider two such elements $e,e'\in G$. Then
$$e\overset{(1)}=e\circ e'\overset{(2)}=e'$$
In $(1)$ we use that $e'$ is a right identity and then in $(2)$ that $e$ is a left identity. Therefore the left identity (which happens to be also a right identity aswell) is uniquely defined. By the way, it is also sufficient to force every element to have a *left* inverse to obtain a group (there is a similiar proof showing that left inverses are also right inverses).

Answer (score 2):

The typical definition is the one you provided. The definition stated in your textbook is that of a left identity, a concept which is weaker (in more general circumstances). Here's an example:

> Take any non-empty set $A$, and define the binary operation
>   $$a \circ b = b$$
>   Then $\circ$ is associative, and every $a \in A$ is a left-identity (but not a right identity unless $|A| = 1$).

If $|A| > 1$, note that we fail to get uniqueness too.

I'm not entirely sure what the textbook is aiming for, but I can prove the following result:

> Suppose $G$ has an associative binary operation $\circ$, and $e$ is a specific left identity. Further, suppose that for all $a \in G$, there exists some $b \in G$ such that $b \circ a = e$. Then $(G, \circ)$ is a group, and $e$ is its (two-sided) identity.

*Proof*. Suppose $a \in G$ and let $b \in G$ such that $b \circ a = e$. Then,
$$(a \circ b) \circ (a \circ b) = a \circ (b \circ a) \circ b = a \circ (e \circ b) = a \circ b.$$
Let $c \in G$ such that $c \circ (a \circ b) = e$, as guaranteed by the hypotheses. Then,
$$e = c \circ (a \circ b) = c \circ ((a \circ b) \circ (a \circ b)) = (c \circ (a \circ b)) \circ (a \circ b) = e \circ (a \circ b) = a \circ b.$$
So, if $e$ is a two-sided identity, then $b$ is a two-sided inverse for $a$. To prove $e$ is a two-sided identity, consider
$$a \circ e = a \circ (b \circ a) = (a \circ b) \circ a = e \circ a = a.$$
QED.

Comment: Thank you, this is was rather helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your first definition is perfectly valid; it is simply that, as a result of the other axioms and itself, it implies the uniqueness of that element as well. Your textbook also leaves out the reversal of the elements, which is also implied. That said, since the properties left out are corollaries, they can be left out, so it is ultimately a matter of preference as to which you use. Personally I prefer the first.

For completeness, proofs that fill in the blanks for your text:

---

## Uniqueness

Suppose $e$ is not unique; i.e. suppose $e'$ is another identity alongside $e$. Then

$$e = e \circ e' = e' \circ e = e'$$

The first equality is since $g \circ e = g$ for all $g$, and the second because $e \circ g = g$ for all $g$. But $e'$ is an identity, so the same must apply to it. After all, "for all $g$" include the identities.

---

## Identity Commutes

Let $e$ be the identity, with $e \circ g = g$ for all $g$. We seek to show $g \circ e = g$ too. Note that

$$g = e \circ g = e \circ (g \circ e) = g \circ e$$

The first equality just is the given in the definition. The second follows because of the same: $g \circ e = g$. Of course, $(g \circ e) \in G$ so the axioms apply to it, and thus $e \circ (g \circ e) = g \circ e$.

A symmetrical argument works starting with $g \circ e = g$ instead (your text randomly flipped between the two).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is the right one, the other one is a *property* of groups that requires a proof. For instance, your definition applies as well to semigroups, but the second one would not be correct in this context. Consider for instance the semigroup $\{a,b\}$ defined by $ab=bb=b$ and $ba=aa=a$. Then both $a$ and $b$ are left identities but none of them is an identity.

Comment: I have yet to learn about semigroups but I'll sure return to your answer when I do so. Thanks!